# converting a string into a tree

Tags: python, string, tree

I want to convert a given string into a tree according to the Python's lexicographic order of strings as the order string , where each word will be compared with next word (root not included ) . That is, a word w is inserted or searched in the left subtree of a node [lefttree, righttree, word] if the comparison w

```
strings will be like this :
string = "sad adsa dqwe fdsf erwa"
```

I did not do anything so far , but i have an idea , which is by splitting the given string **string.split** , assign the first word as a root and for the next words check recursively if the condition returns True .

Comment: Good idea. Let us know if it works for you.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych can you please help with the recursive part

Comment: I assume the result is to be a binary search tree (BST), with each entry a word inserted in the order the words are in the sentence? Is it balanced? What kind of structure do you want for this tree: one list, a list recursively containing lists, an instance of a tree class, or other? (From your question I guess a list of lists, but you should be more clear.) Does each node need a pointer to its parent node? (I guess no.) Finally, you need to show us some code that you have tried, give details what your difficulties are, and show that you have already put significant effort into this problem.

Comment: @RoryDaulton yeah it's a list of lists no pointers , if i had a code i would share it . my defficulties are the recursive part , and inserting list in list . i put already two days into the problem , still stuck on how to build the recursive part . i will try to write a new function and i will add it. thanks for the tipps .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your goal accurately, all you need is a Binary Search Tree (BST) of strings.
Every `Node` of the tree will be a list of lists of the following format: `[left_sub_tree, right_sub_tree, word]`. The empty list will represent the null pointer

Let's implement the simple recursive procedure for inserting new values based on its lexicographical order (it is a default comparison order for strings in Python).

```
def insert(x, word):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return [[], [], word]
    if word < x[2]:
        x[0] = insert(x[0], word)
    elif x[2] < word:
        x[1] = insert(x[1], word)
    return x
```

Now, you can create a BST for your string like that:

```
tree = []
for w in string.split():
    tree = insert(tree, w)
```

The easiest way to see the structure is to print the tree level by level:

```
def print_tree(x, shift):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return
    print_tree(x[0], shift + 2)
    print " " * shift, x[2]
    print_right(x[1], shift + 2)

print_tree(tree, 0)
```

FYI. The above procedure performs so called "in-order" traversal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer yeah that is what i'm trying to do but the presentition of the tree should be list of lists . but again thanks sir , i will be able to unterstand the idea behind your code and present it with list of lists alone

Comment: @Batata please find the appropriate changes in my answer. Now the tree is represented as list of lists.